# Create a new array of data in each loop step in Python 3.4

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.4

I am writting a script in Python 3.4 and I would like to do the following more elegantly.
I have measurement data in a file (2 columns, N rows with N ~ 1000). In order to calculate quantities like average, variance etc. I read in the data as:

```
data_1 = numpy.genfromtxt('measurement_1.out',delimiter='\t')
data_2 = numpy.genfromtxt('measurement_2.out',delimiter='\t')
...
data_20 = numpy.genfromtxt('measurement_20.out',delimiter='\t')
```

However, I would like to do this in a loop, where it is possible to enter the number of measurements (in the example: number=20) to be considered. So far my idea is something like this:

```
for i in range(1,number+1):
 data_'{}'.format(i) = np.genfromtxt('measurement_{}.out'.format(i), delimiter='\t')
```

This obviously does not work.

In other words, my question is: How to create in each step a new array data_i using a loop?

Comment: Collect them in a list and access them with `data[3]` expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in a `dict`. If you want to preserve the order as well, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np

def get_data(number):
   my_data = OrderedDict()
   for i in range(1, number+1):
       my_data['data_{}'.format(i)] = np.genfromtxt('measurement_{}.out'.format(i), delimiter='\t')
   return my_data
```